# How to check whether <ng-content> is empty? (in Angular 2+ till now)

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have a component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'MyContainer',
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <!-- some html skipped -->
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <span *ngIf="????">Display this if ng-content is empty!</span>
        <!-- some html skipped -->
    </div>`
})
export class MyContainer {
}
```

Now, I would like to display some default content if `<ng-content>` for this component is empty. Is there an easy way to do this without accessing the DOM directly?

Comment: FYI, I know the accepted answer works, but I think it's better style to pass in a "useDefault" type input parameter to components, defaulted to false.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Wrap `ng-content` in an HTML element like a `div` to get a local reference to it, then bind the `ngIf` expression to `ref.children.length == 0`:

```
template: `<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div> 
           <span *ngIf=" ! ref.children.length">
              Display this if ng-content is empty!
           </span>`
```

> **Updated for Angular 12;** old logic ("`ref.nativeElement.childNodes.length`") gives error, as `nativeElement` is `undefined` nowadays.

Comment: Is there no alternative way to this? Because this is ugly, compared to Aurelia fallback slots

Comment: It's safer to use `ref.children.length`.  childNodes will contain `text` nodes if you format your html with spaces or new lines, but children will still be empty.

Comment: There is a feature request for a better method on the Angular issue tracker: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12530 (might be worth adding a +1 there).

Comment: Thanks @parliament, for the feedback. I've updated the answer

Comment: I was about to post that this didn't seem to be working until I realized that I used the example of `ref.childNodes.length == 0` instead of `ref.children.length == 0`. It would help a bunch if you could edit the answer to be consistent. Easy mistake, not bashing you. :)

Comment: This trick doesn't work always. If we use ng-container for instance. I assume that is because lifecycle

Comment: I really dislike this answer.  I much prefer to pass a parameter into the component that explicitly states if I'm using the ng-content or not.

Comment: Its even `ref.nativeElement.childNodes.length`. Could this answer be edited please?

Comment: Regarding childNodes vs children - there's valid use cases for both:  
* `children`: looks for DOM elements, but not text nodes  
* `childNodes`: also picks up text nodes
-- 
If you want to project text nodes, childNodes applies, rather than children.

Comment: @StephMW yep, though "technically" the correct answer is childNodes, since the OP's question is "how to check if it's empty".

Comment: @Lerner's answer is the far superior one because it uses the ContentChild API, which is intended by Angular for transcluded content.

Comment: This won't work if you have *ngIfs or any conditionals in your ng-content, because Angular will add comments in its place counting against length of children

Comment: I followed this example and it works fine for me. But I used `!ref.hasChildNodes()` instead of `ref.nativeElement.childNodes.length == 0`

Comment: *beware*: `ref.childNodes.length` indeed delivers zero for only plain text projected, this may or may not be, what you want. (`<ng-content/>: `"hello"`→0, `"<b>hello</b>"`→1)

Comment: This won't work with Angular 10 (Ivy Renderer).  You can get it to work by changing it to:

template: `<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div> 
           <span *ngIf="ref.children.length == 0">
              Display this if ng-content is empty!
           </span>`

Comment: it does the trick, but I gotta agree with @Astronaut, it's quite ugly. In VueJs, we would basically put the default content inside ng-content and be done with it.

Comment: does not work if ref is the component to ngIf, ref is not defined

Answer (score 82):

**EDIT 17.03.2020**

## Pure CSS (2 solutions)

Provides default content if nothing is projected into ng-content.

### Possible selectors:

1. `:only-child` selector. See this post here: [:only-child Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172547/4641479)

   <sup>This one require less code / markup. Support since IE 9: [Can I Use :only-child](https://caniuse.com/#search=only-child)</sup>
2. `:empty` selector. Just read further.

   <sup>Support from IE 9 and partially since IE 7/8: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3</sup>

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ng-content select="my-component"></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="default">
    This shows something default.
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.wrapper:not(:empty) + .default {
    display: none;
}
```

---

**In case it's not working**

Be aware of, that having at least one whitespace is considered to not beeing empty.
Angular removes whitespace, but just in case if it is not:

```
<div class="wrapper"><!--
    --><ng-content select="my-component"></ng-content><!--
--></div>
```

or

```
<div class="wrapper"><ng-content select="my-component"></ng-content></div>
```

Comment: By far this was the best solution for my use case. I wasn't remembering we had an `empty` css pseudoclass

Comment: @Stefan the default content will be rendered anyway...it will be only hide. So, for complex default content this is not the best solution. Is this right?

Comment: @BossOz You are right. It will be rendered (constructor etc. will be called if you have an angular component). This solution works only good for dumb views. If you have complex logic, involving loading or stuff like that, your best bet in my opinion is to write a structural directive, which can get a template / class (however you want to implement it) and depending on the logic, then render the desired component or the default one. The comment section is way too small for an example. I comment again for another example we have in one of our apps.

Comment: One way would be having a component selecting the ContentChildren via a Directive (query with DirectiveClass, but usage as structural directive, so no initial bootstrapping involved with just having the markup): `<loader [data]="allDataWeNeed">  <desired-component *loadingRender><desired-component>  <other-default-component *renderWhenEmptyResult></other-default-component>  </loader>` and in the loading component, you could show perceived performance loading, while the data is loading. You can write / solve it in different ways. This is one demonstration how you could solve it.

Comment: By far the best most elegant solution! thanks man!

Comment: Late to the party. But, yes CSS :empty, this was by far the best solution for my use case. Multiple elements were being passed in via ng-container and wanted to hide addition styling in divs surrounding ng-contents. 

Answer (score 50):

There some missing in @pixelbits answer. We need to check not only `children` property, because any line breaks or spaces in parent template will cause `children` element with blank text\linebreaks.
Better to check `.innerHTML` and `.trim()` it.

**Working example:**

```
<span #ref><ng-content></ng-content></span>
<span *ngIf="!ref.innerHTML.trim()">
    Content if empty
</span>
```

Comment: Can we use this method to check whether child element is empty and hide the parent if so? I tried, no luck

Comment: @KavindaJayakody Yes, this will check child element for empty. Show your code.

Comment: *ngIf="!ref.innerHTML.trim()" This part will cause performance issues. Trim is O(n).

Comment: @RandomCode is right, the function will be called multiple times. A better way is to check `element.children.length`  or `element.childnodes.length`, depending on what you want to ask for.

Comment: It says "ref" is not declared as a variable. Element reference is not working on `ng-content`. I am using angular 11

Answer (score 33):

When you inject the content add a reference variable:

```
<div #content>Some Content</div>
```

and in your component class get a reference to the injected content with @ContentChild()

```
@ContentChild('content') content: ElementRef;
```

so in your component template you can check if the content variable has a value

```
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <span *ngIf="!content">
    Display this if ng-content is empty!
  </span>    
</div>
```

Comment: The OP asked for whether or not ngContent is empty - this means `<MyContainer></MyContainer>`.  Your solution expects users to create a sub-element under MyContainer: `<MyContainer><div #content></div></MyContainer>`.  While this is a possibility, I would not say this is superior.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to display a default content why dont you just use the 'only-child' selector from css.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

for eg:
HTML

```
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div class="default-content">I am default</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.default-content:not(:only-child) {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Rather smart solution, if you don't want to deal with ViewChild and stuffs in the Component. I like it!

Comment: Please notice that transclude content must be an HTML node (not only text)

Answer (score 13):

Inject `elementRef: ElementRef` and check if `elementRef.nativeElement` has any children. This might only work with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`.

Wrap the `<ng-content>` tag and check if it has children. This doesn't work with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`.

```
<div #contentWrapper>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

and check if it has any children

```
@ViewChild('contentWrapper') contentWrapper;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  contentWrapper.nativeElement.childNodes...
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: I downvoted this because of the use of `@ViewChild`. While "Legal", ViewChild should not be used for accessing child-nodes within a template. This is an antipattern because, while parents may _know_ about children, they should not *Couple* to them as it usually leads to **Pathological Coupling**; a more appropriate form of data-transport or request-handling is to use **event-driven methodologies**.

Comment: Why isn't there a declarative, template-driven strategy for accomplishing this? The intuitive approach -- especially coming from the perspective of Angular's history (1.x) -- is to nest your default content within `<ng-content>` and allow it to be overwritten if something is projected/transcluded. It seems, though, that Angular has explicitly denied such efficacy -- what a bummer.

Comment: @Cody thanks for posting a comment to your downvote. Actually I don't follow your argumentation. The template and the components class are a single unit - a component. I don't see why accessing the template from the code should be an antipattern. Angular (2/4) has almost nothing in common with AngularJS except that both are web frameworks and the name.

Comment: Gunter, you make two really good points. Angular should not necessarily hatch with a stigma from the ways of AngularJS. But I'd mark that the first point (and those I've made above) fall toward the philosophical gutter of engineering. That said, I've become something of an expert on Software Coupling and I'd advise against [at least heavy] use of `@ViewChild`. Thanks for adding some balance to my comments -- I find both of our comments just as worthy of consideration as the other.

Comment: @Cody perhaps your strong opinion about `@ViewChild()` comes from the name. "Children" aren't necessarily children, they are just the declarative part of the component (as I see it). If the component instances created for this markup are accesses, this if of course a different story, because it would require knowledge about at least their public interface and this would actually create tight coupling. This is a very interesting discussion. It worries me that I don't have enough time to think about such matters because with such frameworks too often time is burned to find any way at all.

Comment: Not exposing this in the API is the real anti-pattern :-(

Comment: I don't get why you used ViewChild and not ContentChildren. Could you please point where i'm probably mistaken ?

Comment: @Mozgor because I want the wrapper element. With `ContentChild` or `ContentChildren` I can't know what selector to use. This is why I add the wrapper in the current component and then check if projected children were added to it.

Comment: Make much more sense now. Thanks for explaination.

Answer (score 12):

#### Sep 2021

There is another technique to accomplish the default content if not provided from the implementation component by using `*ngTemplateOutlet` directive which allows us to have the customization more control:

##### Example in *source component*:

```
import { Component, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'feature-component',
  templateUrl: './feature-component.component.html',
})
export class FeatureComponent {
  @ContentChild('customTemplate') customTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Then in HTML template:

```
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="customTemplate || defaultTemplate"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #defaultTemplate>
  <div class="default">
    Default content...
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

##### target component:

```
<!-- default content -->

<feature-component></feature-component>


<!-- dynamic content -->

<feature-component>
  <ng-template #customTemplate>
    <div> Custom group items. </div>
  </ng-template>
</feature-component>
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @Unknown May I know the problem you had?

Comment: This is the only solution that lets me remove the element completely if no content was passed in from the outer control.  I was able to do `<mat-dialog-actions *ngIf="actionsTemplate"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionsTemplate"></ng-container></mat-dialog-actions>`.  Now if there's no content, `mat-dialog-actions` is gone rather than being empty and taking up space.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have to hide parent of empty ng-content:

```
<span class="ml-1 wrapper">
  <ng-content>
  </ng-content>
</span>
```

Simple css works:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;

  &:empty {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Angular 10, it has changed slightly.  You would use:

```html
<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div> 
<span *ngIf="ref.children.length == 0">
  Display this if ng-content is empty!
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a solution by using **@ContentChildren** decorator, that is somehow similar to @Lerner's answer.

According to [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren), this decorator:

> Get the QueryList of elements or directives from the content DOM. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value.

So the necessary code in the parent component will be:

```
<app-my-component>
  <div #myComponentContent>
    This is my component content
  </div>
</app-my-component>
```

In the component class:

```
@ContentChildren('myComponentContent') content: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Then, in component template:

```
<div class="container">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <span *ngIf="*ngIf="!content.length""><em>Display this if ng-content is empty!</em></span>
</div>
```

**Full example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjjdqb

I've found this solution implemented in angular components, for `matSuffix`, in the [form-field](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/cf11ed2234be6743890d267a44435b844cf6c468/src/material/form-field/form-field.html#L60-L62) component.

In the situation when the content of the component is injected later on, **after** the app is initialised, we can also use a reactive implementation, by subscribing to the `changes` event of the `QueryList`:

```
export class MyComponentComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
  private _subscription: Subscription;
  public hasContent: boolean;

  @ContentChildren('myComponentContent') content: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.hasContent = (this.content.length > 0);
    this._subscription = this.content.changes.subscribe(() => {
      // do something when content updates
      //
      this.hasContent = (this.content.length > 0);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**Full example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-essvnq

Answer (score 2):

`<ng-content #ref></ng-content>` shows error "ref" is not declared.
The following is working in Angular 11 (Probably 10 also):

```
<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!ref.hasChildNodes()">
       Default Content
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

in angular 11 I use this and works fine.

template file :

```
 <h3 class="card-label" #titleBlock>
      <ng-content select="[title]" ></ng-content>
 </h3>
```

component:

```
@ViewChild('titleBlock') titleBlock: ElementRef;
hasTitle: boolean;


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.titleBlock && this.titleBlock.nativeElement.innerHTML.trim().length > 0)
    {
        this.hasTitle=  true;
    }
    else
    {
       this.hasTitle=  false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 12, the console reports the following for me:

> Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

There seems to exist a specific attribute `childElementCount` which you can use for this case.

As a consequence, I used this successfully, which does not wrap the dynamic content into additional elements/tags:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- some html skipped -->

  <ng-container #someContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
  <span 
    *ngIf="
      someContent.childElementCount === undefined || 
      someContent.childElementCount === 0
    "
  >
    Display this if ng-content is empty!
  </span>

  <!-- some html skipped -->
</div>
```

Comment: somehow hasChildNodes() is not working for me. this helped

Answer (score 1):

This solution has worked for me (on angular version 12.0.2).
Note that this will probably not work if your content is dynamic and changes from empty to non-empty (or the other way) after the component was already loaded.
That can be fixed by adding code that changes `hasContent` inside `ngOnChanges`.

Example:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<div [ngClass]="[hasContent ? 'has-content' : 'no-content']">
        <span #contentRef>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </span>
    </div>']
})
export class Momponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('contentRef', {static: false}) contentRef;

    hasContent: boolean;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.hasContent = this.contentRef?.nativeElement?.childNodes?.length > 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good answers here, though a working solution seems to change through the years.

In Angular 15, the following seems to work best for me, self-contained and concise:

```
<div #content><ng-content></ng-content></div>
<div *ngIf="!content.childElementCount">
    <h1>Default Content Goes Here!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd share. In my particular instance, I did not want any wrapper **div** elements and had to purely use **ng-container** or **ng-template**.

component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
})
export class AitStoryDivComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(public ref: ElementRef) { }

    showContent = true;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.showContent = this.ref.nativeElement.children.length > 0
    }

}
```

component.html

```
<ng-template #textTemplate>
    Some default text if component does not have ng-content
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngIf="showContent; else textTemplate">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The key is defaulting showContent to true and then updating it after the view has been initialized.

To have this update real-time afterwards, you could add a ngOnChanges and update the showContent property.

Answer (score -2):

You can split it into two components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'MyContainer',
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <!-- some html skipped -->
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <!-- some html skipped -->
    </div>`
})
export class MyContainer {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'MyContainerNoContent',
    template: `
    <MyContainer>
        <span>Display this if ng-content is empty!</span>
    </MyContainer>`
})
export class MyContainerNoContent {
}
```

and use MyContainer if you want to add content and MyContainerNoContent for the default content.