# Angular 2 counting empty div as having 2 childNodes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to check whether an `ng-content` is empty or not, so I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty) and took the accepted answer.

However I'm not getting the desired results.

I'm setting a local template variable called `#target` and then accessing its `childNodes` property and checking its length:

```
<header class="{{ns}}-dm-header">
    <button class="{{ns}}-dm-toggle" [ngClass]="{fluid: !target.childNodes.length}" (click)="toggle()">{{placeholder}}</button>

    // Checking to see the length
    <code>{{target.childNodes.length}}</code>

    <div class="{{ns}}-dm-content-target" #target>
      <ng-content select="[target]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is what `#target` contains after render:

```
<div _ngcontent-mcb-3="" class="bch-dm-content-target"></div>
```

When I check the length with `{{target.childNodes.length}}` it says that `#target` has a childNodes length of 2 despite it being empty.

What exactly is it counting as childNodes if it's empty and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is not minified/trimmed, your snippet will contain text nodes caused by the whitespaces used for indentation/formatting

```
<div class="{{ns}}-dm-content-target" #target>
  <ng-content select="[target]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

If you want to avoid that, write the following:

```
<div class="{{ns}}-dm-content-target" #target><ng-content select="[target]"></ng-content></div>
```

Comment: That is the dumbest thing I've ever heard if this is the case, will have to test it and get back to you.