# If ng-content has content or empty Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to understand how to create an if to show when a `ng-content` is empty.

```
<div #contentWrapper [hidden]="isOpen">
    <ng-content ></ng-content>
</div>

<span *ngIf="contentWrapper.childNodes.length == 0">
    <p>Display this if ng-content is empty!</p>
</span>
```

I've tried to use that one to show a display data when the content is empty but even if the information is empty doesn't show the `<span>` tag

Thanks, always grateful for your help.

Comment: Look on my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563380/1296298

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `children` instead of `childNodes`. Angular creates comment nodes for `*ngIf* which are counted by`childNodes`

```
<div #contentWrapper [hidden]="isOpen">
    <ng-content ></ng-content>
</div>

<span *ngIf="contentWrapper.children.length == 0">
    <p>Display this if ng-content is empty!</p>
</span>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tyN286R1waD2P97d8JGL?p=preview)

Comment: I assume that won't work if ngIf is on the wrapper itself

Comment: @Ced no, in this case you have to use something like `@ViewChild('contentWrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;` and `*ngIf="wrapper?.nativeElement?.children?.length"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that does not seem to work. I'm struggling right now with the same issue: removing an element from the DOM when the embedded `<ng-content>` is empty. Guess that can only be solved through template projection, but how? No recipe found yet.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what the problem is. I'd suggest you create a new question with the code that shows how to reproduce and what you try to accomplish.