# Is it possible to set default value to <ng-content>

Tags: angular, default-value, angular2-ngcontent

I was just learning the use of `Transluction` in `angular2` from this tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

I was able to use the `<ng-content>` tag for some content like:

```
<ng-content select="[my-block-header]"></ng-content>
```

and it lies in component where `my-block` selector is attached.

It renders the content from my other component as:

```
<my-block>
    <div class="box-header" my-block-header> <--added the slot selector here
        <h3 class="box-title">
            My title
        </h3>
    </div>
</my-block>
```

**The issue is:**

**Is it possible to add the default value to the `<ng-content>` block which could be used if we didn't pass any value?**

As for now if there is no value passed there will be blank page in it's position.

**Edit:**

When i was trying to test there was newer version of `zone.js` which was not allowing the correct error to be displayed, therefore i was getting the error as:

```
Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; 
Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
```

But when i changed the version of `zone.js` to `0.7.2` the error was clearly mentioned in the console as:

```
zone.js:392 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
<ng-content> element cannot have content.
```

**So, it confirms that there can't be any default value set to `<ng-content>`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Angular 2 how to check whether <ng-content> is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty)

Answer (score 26):

From angular 10 the following works:

```
<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div>
<ng-container *ngIf="!ref.hasChildNodes()">
   Default Content
</ng-container>
```

It simply means, if the div `ref` doesn't have any child nodes (That means, `ng-content` is empty), then render the `ng-container` having the "Default Content".

Answer (score 8):

Just Use:

```
<ng-content #myBlockHeader select="[my-block-header]"></ng-content>
<div *ngIf="!myBlockHeader">Default Content</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me (angular 9). There are several working solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty

Answer (score -8):

What if you put some markup within the `<ng-content>` tag?

```
<ng-content select="[my-block-header]">
  <p>Some default markup here</p>
</ng-content>
```

Comment: It gives me the error as: `Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined`

Comment: Bummer. Then, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: We cannot set the default value on the <ng-content>. Now the error message clearly mentions it:
`<ng-content> element cannot have content.`

Comment: With `ViewEncapsulation.Native` you can use the `<content>` or `<slot>` element. `<content>` supports default content, don't know about `<slot>`. `Native` is currently not well supported though. Especially styling can become a problem because `>>>` or `/deep/` won't work anymore.

Comment: Is there any better options than using `<content>`? I have got the default values using `<content>`  but it doesn't let me override unless i use `ViewEncapsulation.Native` and as you told earlier it is breaking my stylings too :(