# How to provide a fallback for empty ng-content in Angular?

Tags: angular

Say, I have a component that accepts ng-content in its template:

but I would like the component to display some default content as a fallback, in case nothing is provided as ng-content. Is there a *ngIf type of directive that I could apply as a test whether ng-content is not empty?

Comment: There is nothing out-of-the box, that you can use

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check for projected content yourself and show alternative content when none was found:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="hasContent">alternative content</div>
    <div #wrapper>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;
  hasContent = false;
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.hasContent = this.wrapper.childNodes.length > 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788194/1751792

Answer (score 4):

Template only solution (it handle [SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and case when content has only spaces or line-breaks):

```
<div *ngIf="!(wrapper.innerHTML||'').trim()">alternative content</div>

<div #wrapper>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>`
```

Comment: @Azarus can you provide alternative solution which handle case when contents has only spaces line/breaks without using native browser DOM element? (and don't forget that `@ContentChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;` also returns native browser DOM element)

Comment: Indeed angular provides native access to DOM properties however i call it the "angular way" syndrome. The code above might break with SSR for example. The only thing you could do to safely access thise properties is to check if the platform is the browsers ui thread otherwise skip the code. Also to manipulate DOM the renderer2 is preferred.

Comment: @Azarus I update answer to handle case when `#wrapper` not contains `innerHTML` property (as the way of checking that platform is browser or not) - now this code is safe and should not brake SSR. `@ContentChild` approach (which is not bad) have same problem and need probably similar solution.

Comment: Updated answer is very nice. Hopefully it will recover from the negative votes soon!