# Check if ng-content is empty and if not use it in template for another component (Angular 2+)

Tags: angular, angular2-template, kendo-ui-angular2

All solution I found uses html and `children.length` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty).
I found [this great article](https://medium.com/@MichalCafe/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9), but as the author said, the post is an old and new feature in Angular4 may be superior.

My problem is that I have a component which template could be changed:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist>
    <ng-template kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
        <div>Some template</div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

And I use this component in another component, where I would like to offer user option to change the template or not via `<ng-content>`.

Something like this:

```
//my-component
<kendo-dropdownlist>
    <ng-template *ngIf="CheckIfNgContentIsNotEmpty" kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Is this possible with Angular4?

*For example:*

```
<my-component></my-component>   //this should NOT render <ng-template *ngIf="CheckIfNgContentIsNotEmpty" kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem></ng-template>

<my-component><div>Foo</div></my-component> //this should render <ng-template *ngIf...
```