# Angular: wrap transcluded content if it exists

Tags: angular, angular-template, transclusion

How can I wrap transcluded content, only if it exists?

For example, template of `my-component`:

```
<div>
    ...
    <div *ngIf="isInvalid" class="error">
        <h2>Extra errors:</h2>
        <ng-content select="extra-error-messages"></ng-content>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The component could be used so

```
<my-component>
    <extra-error-messages>
       Do not ever try this!
    </extra-error-messages>
</my-component>
```

In this case `div.error` should be shown, or it could be used so

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

In this case `div.error` should not appear even if `isInvalid` is  `true`.

Comment: `[class.error]="isInvalid"`

Comment: sorry for previous comment and i misunderstand.

Comment: @RachChen the `div` should not appear if it is valid or has no `<extra-error-messages>`

Comment: which `div` do you mean?

Comment: @RachChen I mean the whole `<div *ngIf="isInvalid" class="error">` whould not appear, that's why `*hgIf` and not only `error`-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get hold of `extra-error-messages` component through `@ContentChild` and check whether it is presented in parent template.

So this should work in your case:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div>
        <h2>My component</h2>
        <div *ngIf="isInvalid && errorMessage" class="error">
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
                         check whether extra-error-messages is presented
            <h2>Extra errors:</h2>
            <ng-content select="extra-error-messages"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>

  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent  {
  isInvalid = true;

  @ContentChild(ErrorMessagesComponent) errorMessage; // get transcluded component
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ri3zw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

For more complex scenario see:

- [In Angular 2 how to check whether <ng-content> is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty)

Comment: @yurzuy thanks a lot!
Your example has one little error: the extra-error-message does not appear...

Comment: Do you mean `Do not ever try this!`? Updated example

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it does not work with `<ng-container ngProjectAs="extra-error-messages">`...

Comment: I don't see any ngProjectAs in your example.

Comment: Of course, sorry. This question follows the yesterdays' question about `ngProjectAs`, but with your help I already found the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is an example with `ngProjectAs` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erwsmj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html I created `NgProjectAsDirective` to solve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161812/discussion-between-gennadiy-litvinyuk-and-yurzui).

Comment: @yurzui Where do you get `ErrorMessagesComponent` inside the content child?  That's the only part I don't get