# Conditional rendering of multiple transclusion

Tags: angular

Let's say you have an AccordionComponent with some PanelComponents and you want to project content into these PanelComponents: There is a `main` slot for whatever and also a `buttons` slot, whose content gets projected into a `div.button-bar`.

However, `div.button-bar` should only be rendered, if there is any content to be projected into the `buttons` slot.

Is it anyhow possible to check (within the template) if there is some content to projected into a specific slot and simply use an `*ngIf`?

**accordion.component.html**

```
<app-panel [panelTitle]="'Panel 1'">
  <p main>I am a paragraph and I have something to say</p>
  <button buttons>Click</button>
</app-panel>

<app-panel [panelTitle]="'Panel 2'">
  <p main>I am a paragraph as well, but I'm too cool for a button.</p>
  </app-panel>
<app-panel [panelTitle]="'Panel 3'"></app-panel>
```

**panel.component.html**

```
<header>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
</header>

<div class="content">

  <ng-content select="[main]"></ng-content>

  <div class="button-bar">
    <ng-content select="[buttons]"></ng-content>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty