# How to read nested directive?

Tags: angular

I have a custom button component with a structure like this one (simplified version of code for readability purposes):

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <ng-content select="[appButtonIcon]"></ng-content>
    <i *ngIf="iconClass && !customIcon" class="fa {{iconClass}}"></i>
    {{isIconButton ? '' : text}}
</button>
```

TS:

```
@ContentChild(ButtonIconDirective, { static: true }) customIcon: ButtonIconDirective;
```

And it works fine. Note, please, the line `<ng-content select="[appButtonIcon]"></ng-content>`. I created a custom directive `appButtonIcon` so the user can add a custom icon, like SVG content, for example. This is working properly, I can do both:

#### 1

```
<custom-button text="Test" (clicked)="onClick()">
    <svg appButtonIcon ...>
        <path ... />
    </svg>
</custom-button>
```

#### 2

```
<custom-button text="Test" (clicked)="onClick()" iconClass="fa-folder">
</custom-button>
```

And they work properly. The problem starts when I add this custom button as part of another custom component, my custom datepicker toggle. When I do so, only of the options will work. I can only use a regular icon class or always use a custom icon with the `appButtonIcon` directive:

### Custom datepicker toggle HTML

Ideal(?):

```
<app-custom-button (click)="open($event)" iconClass="fa-calendar" isIconButton="true">
    <ng-content select="[appButtonIcon]"></ng-content>
</app-custom-button>
```

But it doesn't work, `app-custom-button` can never read the content I add inside the custom datepicker toggle with the directive `appButtonIcon`.

Version only working if custom icons are set:

```
<app-custom-button (click)="open($event)" iconClass="fa-calendar" isIconButton="true">
    <ng-container appButtonIcon>
        <ng-content select="[appButtonIcon]"></ng-content>
    </ng-container>
</app-custom-button>
```

The problem with this approach is, that, since I had to manually add the `ng-container` with the `appButtonIcon` directive, it's always going to be read by the button (obviously), even when there's no content set by the user of the custom datepicker toggle. But if I remove that, the inner content is never read, and the `fa-calendar` class always used. Is there a way to fix that?

Please take a look at StackBlitz for a "working" example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymxtmv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the `ngProjectAs` directive. You can forward the reference to the `custom-button` by doing the following:

```html
<app-custom-button (click)="open($event)" iconClass="fa-calendar" isIconButton="true">
    <ng-content ngProjectAs="[appButtonIcon]" select="[appButtonIcon]"></ng-content>
</app-custom-button>
```

With this change you will need to modify the custom button a bit to account for the case when no `customIcon` is provided. `ngProjectAs` is a compiler trick to tell angular to interpret it as a `ButtonIconDirective` but it is not actually one so at run time the reference in the class is undefined. Update the custom button template to the following:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span #ref>
    <ng-content select="[appButtonIcon]"></ng-content>
  </span>
  <i *ngIf="iconClass && ref.childNodes.length === 0" class="fa {{iconClass}}"></i>
  {{isIconButton ? '' : text}}
</button>
```

This ref logic was derived from this question: [In Angular 2 how to check whether <ng-content> is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty/35111426)

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skfvbm)

Comment: Thank you! It sounds a little bit "hacky" to me, but I honestly didn't think it'd look any different than that :D