# Hide mat-menu if ng content is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have a a basic mat-menu dropDown menu

```
     <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
     <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
     </mat-menu>
```

And i want to hide the menu button if there is no buttons in menu, 'ng-content' is empty.

is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Angular 2 how to check whether <ng-content> is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty)

Comment: @developer033 actually no,  because ng-content is always empty, mat-menu removes it somhow.