# How to remove parent element if ng-content is empty

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-ngcontent

I want to hide remove `div.parent` if `ng-content` is empty from bellow code

```
<div class="parent">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

I tried using reference like bellow, but seems to be not working

```
<div class="parent" *ngIf="!child.children.length">
  <div class="child"> 
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a better approach to remove parent element if `ng-content` is empty?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247762/993328

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I dont want to do it using CSS

Comment: Is parent a component or the index.html

Comment: @JamesD It is a component

Comment: you could use a service with an observable that communicates that whatever ng-content contains has elements, if not, don't display it

Comment: ng-content is what makes you need a service, else you could just use an event emitter, which is passed back to the parent

Answer (score 3):

If you have no access to the ng-content nor to the possible input from the people using your components, then you have to validate it with javascript or CSS

**CSS method:**

```css
.displayNoneWhenEmpty:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="displayNoneWhenEmpty">Not Empty</div>

<div class="displayNoneWhenEmpty"></div>
```

[reference](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/16996/hide-parent-div-when-no-child-div-inside)

**Javascript method:**

Add an id to the parent div and a boolean check:

```html
<div class="parent" id="parentDivId" *ngIf="hideParent">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then in your component add a boolean variable, which you set in the constructor

```js
hideParent: boolean = false;
constructor(){
    hideParent = document.getElementById("parentDivId")?.childElementCount > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your name for parent is confusing considering the ng-content holder is normally the child of another component which calls it.

```html
<div class="parent">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

The calling HTML would look something like this:
(where your ng-content is in app-footer)

```html
<app-footer>
   <p>MY CONTENT TO THE ng-content THINGY</p>
</app-footer>
```

You'll want to upgrade your app-footer (ng-content component) to have an input field

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; 

//.......
export class FooterComponent {
  @Input() displayParentDiv = true;
```

And in you template

```html
<div class="parent" *ngIf="displayParentDiv">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

And then in your footer (ng-content holder) file:

```html
<p>Pass the input false if you don't want it displayed:</p>
<app-footer [displayParentDiv]="false">
   <p>MY CONTENT TO THE ng-content THINGY</p>
</app-footer>

<p> To display it, don't give it any value considering default is true</p>
<app-footer>
   <p>MY CONTENT TO THE ng-content THINGY</p>
</app-footer>
```

Example code of a  object which I reuse in many of my projects is the use of a material icon navigation item for a toolbar is the code below. Notice that I defaulted all the values, making them not obligated fields, I could for instance only pass an material icon reference and no hint or routerlink

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ps-nav-item',
  template: `
    <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="routerLink" (click)="navigate.emit()">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{ icon }}</mat-icon>
      <span mat-line><ng-content></ng-content></span>
      <span mat-line class="secondary">{{ hint }}</span>
    </a>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .secondary {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class NavItemComponent {
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() hint = '';
  @Input() routerLink: string | any[] = '/';
  @Output() navigate = new EventEmitter();
}
```

The parents HTML then calls this multiple times:

```html
        <ps-nav-item (navigate)="closeSidenav()" *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async" routerLink="/" icon="book" hint="View your report collection">
          My Collection
        </ps-nav-item>
        <ps-nav-item (navigate)="closeSidenav()" *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async" routerLink="/reports/find" icon="search" hint="Search for a report!">
          Browse Reports
        </ps-nav-item>
        <ps-nav-item (navigate)="closeSidenav()" *ngIf="!(loggedIn$ | async)">
          Sign In
        </ps-nav-item>
        <ps-nav-item (navigate)="logout()" *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async">
          Sign Out
        </ps-nav-item>
```

ref [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#configuring-the-child-component)

Comment: I cannot pass this - `[displayParentDiv]="false"`

Comment: I assume you know if you'll be passing adding HTML content when you call the component. Check the added example. You cannot pass it because it's bugging or because of another reason?

Comment: i cannot pass it, because i am not accessible to that code, whatever comes inside `ng-content` i have to display

Comment: So somebody else is calling your code?

Comment: Yes, and we cannot defined the code structure for them

Comment: Then I think the best way is by doing it with CSS as mentioned by @GaurangDhorda or checking it with some javascript that accesses the dom

Answer (score 1):

You can not reference a class like that. I think you want to reference an element, for that you would use `#` on the element. But that won't help you either. Parent is rendered before child is and if parent is removed from DOM because of child changes you would stumble on an error `Expression Changed After It Has Been Checked`. For that I have implemented to `viewChild` of `parentRef` in cycle `ngAfterContentChecked` and from that we count if child has any children (if ng-container has any elements). If it does have children we remove parent.

If for some reason you want to remove parent a later time you can call `removeParent()` to do so.

Edit `children = [1,2,3]` to observe effects of having children and not having them.

```html
<p>Remove parent if child is empty (look console)</p>
<br>
<div class="parent" *ngIf="!hideParent">
  I am parent
  <div class="child" #childRef> 
    <ng-container *ngFor="let child of children">
      <div>I am child nr: # {{child}}<br></div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentChecked {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('childRef') child: ElementRef;
  hideParent: boolean = false;
  children = [1, 2, 3];
  parentElem: any;

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.removeParent();
  }

  removeParent() {
    if (this.child) {
      let childrenCount = this.child.nativeElement.childElementCount;
      console.log('child: ', this.child);
      console.log('child elements in child: ', childrenCount);
      if (childrenCount == 0) {
        console.log('hiding');
        this.hideParent = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4krctv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: if you inspect, i can see `<div>` in it

Comment: I can't see it. https://ibb.co/hRKtrG9

Comment: But in your example, `child` is not empty, still it is removed

Comment: Oh you want to remove then the child of the parent is empty, not when parent has no children. Let's just move the `#` ref on to the children then. Please check my example - I have updated it.

Comment: No basically i want to remove parent if child is empty

Comment: It is done like so. Have you re-checked the demo on my answer?

Comment: No, your code doesn't seems to be, what i am expecting to be

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved like this:

```html
<div #parentRef *ngIf="showParent" class="parent">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

```js
@ViewChild('parentRef') parentRef: ElementRef;

  showParent: boolean = true;;

  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(!this.parentRef?.nativeElement.children){
      this.showParent = false;
    }
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

This feels very hacky, but I haven't found a neater solution in a few hours of playing.

(I introduced `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` in order to prevent the `expression has changed after it was checked...` error)

Answer (score 0):

My team uses a very Angular solution. Doesn't require any CSS or DOM checking/manipulating.

*May only work if you're selecting a specific sub-set of the content supplied by the consumer, using `<ng-content select=... >`.*

In the TS you can dynamically check what content has been supplied by the consumer using `@ContentChildren`.

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective)
myDirectiveChildren: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

If there's at least one content child, show parent the div. Otherwise hide the whole thing.

```
<div *ngIf="myDirectiveChildren.length > 0">
 <ng-content select="[myDirective]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

This list of content is updated dynamically by Angular. It also doesn't care if that parent element exists or not, the list represents the content supplied by the consumer regardless of where/if it's displayed.

Unfortunately, I just can't find any way to get `@ContentChildren()` to include all child content, it always takes a parameter. A solution where the consumer doesn't have to tag any content with a directive would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS solution which hides the parent (`display: none`) instead of removing it from the DOM:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      Parent content (hidden when ng-content is empty)
      <div class="ng-content-container">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .parent:has(.ng-content-container:empty) {
        display: none;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class NavItemComponent {}
```