# How to declare ng-content in a template?

Tags: angular

How do I add the  component to the templateUrl?

The `template` and `templateUrl` is interchangeable either this or that, and I already have a `templateUrl` declared with the template so how can I add another variable to it?

I already have one variable assigned to `templateUrl` so how can I add another?

```
@Component({
selector: 'selectorTest',
templateUrl: './detail-test.component.html', '<ng-conent></ng-content>'
})
```

I wanted to add simply after the comma, but I get the error that `Property assigment expected`.
I also tried to add another `templateUrl` property but there can only be one.

Comment: `templateUrl` is a `string` pointing to your template file. You should put your markup in this HTML file. Or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: *The template and templateUrl is interchangeable either this or that* And who do you think decides what is chosen?

Comment: @pzaenger I want to use `content-projection`, so I need to declare `ng-content` in the documentation is something like this: template: 
    
    `<ng-content></ng-content>`.
This is declared `ng-content` in `template` directly, and in my case I have a `templateUrl` with the template so it is to it i.e. to this file that I need to add '<ng-content></ng-content>'?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Obviously, I'm deciding. What I mean is whether `<ng-content></ng-content>`  should be declared in the file that `templateUrl` points to, or declared like this: `templateUrl`:`<ng-content></ng-content>'`.

Comment: I think this issue should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty-in-angular-2-till-now

Answer (score 0):

`templateUrl` is meant to recieve only a path argument, the path to a template file.

I would advise you to add the `<ng-content></ng-content>` into the file pointed by `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from Angular's Doc:

> 1 `template`: An inline template for an Angular component. If provided, do not supply a template file using `templateUrl`.
>
> 2 `templateUrl`: The relative path or absolute URL of a template file for an Angular component. If provided, do not supply an inline template using `template`.

This means that you can only use one or the other. You can't combine them.

In your case, you can do **one** of the following:

---

### 1. `template` example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
             <h2> This is a template example. Below is the ng-content </h2>
             <ng-content></ng-content>
            `
})
export class ExampleComponent {

}
```

### 2. `templateUrl` example:

```js
// example.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent {

}
```

```html
// example.component.html

<h2>This is a templateUrl example. Below is the ng-content</h2>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

---