# Check if ng content is empty in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I have a component that has two TemplateRefs

`@ViewChild('optionContent') optionContent: TemplateRef<unknown>; @ViewChild('selectContent') selectContent: TemplateRef<unknown>;`
with template:

```
<ng-template #optionContent>
      <ng-content select="[option]"></ng-content>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #selectContent>
      <ng-content select="[select]"></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
```

I am passing the above component in its parent and checking if selectcontent exists, it should render the selectcontent else optioncontent but I can not come up with a condition. I am using the following logic in the parent template but it is not working:

`<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="state?.selectedItem?.selectContent ?? state?.selectedItem?.optionContent" ></ng-container>`

Is there any other way to acheive this?

I tried with the following condition:

`<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="state?.selectedItem?.selectContent ?? state?.selectedItem?.optionContent" ></ng-container>`

Comment: my child template is:

<ng-template #optionContent>
      <ng-content select="[option]"></ng-content>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #selectContent>
      <ng-content select="[select]"></ng-content>
    </ng-template>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether <ng-content> is empty? (in Angular 2+ till now)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty-in-angular-2-till-now)

Answer (score 0):

You wanna check if any `ng-content` is empty, right?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35111426/4472932) is a possible solution on Stackoverflow.

```
template: `<div #ref><ng-content></ng-content></div> 
           <span *ngIf="!ref.children.length">
              Display this if ng-content is empty!
           </span>`
```

So in short words: You can handle it with `css` but your solution is absolutely fine.

**CSS Example**

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ng-content select="my-component"></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="default">
    This shows something default.
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.wrapper:not(:empty) + .default {
    display: none;
}
```